# Pytest: how to run some test after all other tests regardless of markers

Tags: python, pytest, markers, autotest

I have test groups with markers: "smoke"

```
@pytest.mark.smoke
def test_add_data_source():
.....

@pytest.mark.smoke
def test_del_data_source():
.....
```

And I started the test using the command:

```
pytest --strict -s -v -m smoke --alluredir=allure-results
```

It's ok, all worked.

Now I need to copy my Allure files into Allure Report services into Kubernetes after all tests are finished. This needs to run for any cases, independent of used markers. I used the teardown syntax:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module",autouse=True)
def global_fixture():
    yield
    send_result()
```

but in this case, it doesn't sent the Allure files for the last test in a group. But if I use an additional test like this - it worked:

```
@pytest.mark.smoke
def test_global_fixture():
    send_result()
```

But I need to run this test regardless of any filters for markers. At shall be run after all other tests by both these commands:

```
pytest --strict -s -v -m smoke --alluredir=allure-results
pytest --strict -s -v --alluredir=allure-results
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Actually, the teardown syntax in your fixture should work. You should check if you don't get there at all (would be strange), or `send_result()` fails for some reason.

Comment: send_result() permanently do not send only the last files pack whatever they are. As example if alltogether there are 10 smoke tests - 9 work, tenth doen't sent, if 20 - 19 - ok, twentieth - not sent

Comment: Ok, so this is probaly a scope problem - the last result is not ready yet because you haven't left the scope of the last test, or something like this. Or a timing problem... hm

Comment: I would recommend to first check if a session-scoped fixture behaves better, and if that doesn't work, try to write a `pytest_sessionfinish` hook instead.

Comment: Excelent! With 'pytest_sessionfinish' fixsture it works!!! Thank you very much, dear friend!!!
But I have to explore this functionality details, I never meet 'pytest_sessionfinish' before.

Comment: Glad I could help!